# Angular2 input validation needs to meet some criteria

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm a little confused about input validation in Angular2.
I see that we can use `pattern`, `maxlength`, `minlength` and `required`.

How would I use these to meet this criteria:

- Number between 0 - 999
- String that has between 1 and 17 characters

thanks

Comment: You can use [`pipes`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) which are almost solely used for formatting input.

Comment: hello, any exemple @Scrambo ?

Comment: My apologies, I may have screwed up my formatting, the word 'pipes' in my previous comment is actually a link. The link has an example of how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with **pattern**

for example: to restrict the input to be a number between 0-999 you can use

```
pattern="^[\d]*$"
```

and

```
maxlength="3"
```

for validating string that has 1-17 characters

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$"
```

and

```
maxlength="17", minlength="1"
```

I haven't tested these regexes but they should be fine

Answer (score 0):

pattern="[0-9]{1,3}" ---> Number between 0 - 999

pattern="[A-Za-z1-9]{0,17}" ---> String that has between 1 and 17 characters